# multichannel support for Windows Media Foundation AAC encoder

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, ms-media-foundation

I'm writing a program using Windows Media Foundation AAC encoder to encode audio. According to documentation here - [AAC Encoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742785) - 6 channels is supported.
But in my program when I set it to 6, I'll get a MF_E_INVALIDMEIDATYPE error.
Below is my code

```
CLSID* pCLSIDs = NULL;// Pointer to an array of CLISDs.
UINT32 nCount = 0;
MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO encoderInfo;
encoderInfo.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Audio; 
encoderInfo.guidSubtype = MFAudioFormat_AAC;// AAC Encoder class id is not exposed, so we have to enumerate      

HRESULT hr = fpMFTEnum(MFT_CATEGORY_AUDIO_ENCODER, 0, NULL, &encoderInfo, NULL, &pCLSIDs, &nCount);
ciEncoder.CreateObject(pCLSIDs[0], IID_IMFTransform);
LComObject<IMFMediaType> ciInputType;  // Input media type of the encoder
hr = fpMFCreateMediaType((IMFMediaType**)(ciInputType.GetAssignablePtrRef()));
hr = ciInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
hr = ciInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);
hr = ciInputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16); // must be 16
hr = ciInputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, Samplerate);
hr = ciInputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, Channels); //Must be 1 (mono)or 2 (stereo), or 6 (5.1).
hr = ciEncoder->SetInputType(0, ciInputType.get(), 0);      
if (FAILED(hr)) {
   LDEBUG("Failed to set encoder input meida type"); 
   break;      
}
```

I've removed all error handling code and please ignore my wrapper on the COM object.

ciEncoder->SetInputType() will fail when Channels == 6. But when Channels == 1 or 2, SetInputType succeeds. It happens on both 32 and 64 bit Win7 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original Windows 7 AAC Encoder [did not have support for 5.1 audio](http://web.archive.org/web/20131203094109/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It was added later with newer OS releases (Windows 8 or 8.1). MSDN article does not have a mention of this.

Comment: I can't make this work on the latest Windows 10.
Fails whenever I call writer->SetInputMediaType(index, pMediaTypeIn, nullptr)
Any specifics needed to make this work? according to official documentation, no

Comment: I guess it's still possible even though may be tricky. The media type might have to have good channel mask, for example. I would say that one could try to create media type from valid WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE for such type and/or check out what decoder for 5.1 AAC suggests. I'd say with sufficient focus on such detail 5.1 encoder would take off.